# Colouring in a circle perfectly without using the fill-bucket

Tags: fill, krita

[image]

[**Video**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3sz9cg2gbnt6e0y/Krita.mp4?dl=0)

As you can see in the video, I made a circle, then coloured it in manually - and then, it went over the outline.

How do you avoid this? I would like to colour an object without having to go through the hassle of carefully erasing it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to create a vector layer.  Then make a circle. Then select the circle with the *Select Shapes tool*.

Then you can change the stroke and fill in the Tool Options. Because the object is a vector, you can do this as many times as you like.

Although changing the fill here looks like I'm using the Fill Bucket tool, it's not the same thing. The fill is actually part of the vector shape itself.

Example

[image]

Note: Vector shapes are not limited to just circles or geometric shapes. You can create your own vector shapes with the Bézier Curve tool, and similarly apply strokes and fills to it.

[image]

Comment: A little background - I'm not colouring a circle, but I'm drawing a stripy shirt on an animal - I just thought I'd phrase my question to be less confusing that way.

Comment: I have already drawn my outline - when I try to draw a line (because it is a stripy shirt), you can see the line go across the arms. This is a video of me doing it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zwjclkmeur8um5v/Krita2.mp4?dl=0

Comment: @WaffleBoots - yeah, but your question specifically asks about perfectly filling a circle. So that's what I answered. The specifics of what you are actually trying to do are important here, and because you missed them out, you got an answer you didn't really want.  This is what we call an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - always try to avoid these.

Comment: Sorry - I'm still kind of new here, I just wanted to make my question less confusing - I will try to avoid that as much as possible. Thank you!

Comment: @WaffleBoots No worries.  No need to apologize - everybody can make mistakes ;)